# Setting up an SSL certificate for a domain that uses an A-record redirect to a domain with an existing SSL cert

Tags: ssl, https, dns, sni

I am working on a client's site - we'll call it checkers.com - that I previously bought an SSL certificate for. They bought a european domain - checkers.eu - that that uses an A-record redirect to point to checkers.com, but setting up an SSL certificate for that domain fails because it's technically on the same IP address as the checkers.com site, and that's not allowed. How would I go about setting up an SSL certificate on checkers.eu when that domain just redirects to a domain that already has an SSL certificate?

Comment: "...but setting up an SSL certificate for that domain fails...". What do you mean by "setting up"? How does it fail?

Comment: Get an SSL certificate that covers all the names the site plans to use.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I believe they simply can't install it there. All they told me was "there was a hiccup". I will ask them to clarify.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz we bought an SSL certificate and when I installed it I was told that it would correspond to the site name set on the server name, which is checkers.com. So I imagine it covers all subdomains of checkers.com, but nothing with a different extension.

Comment: You can buy a certificate that supports a list of hostnames, and they do not have to have a subdomain relationship. If someone types in "https ://checkers.eu" into their browser, then the certificate used to authenticate the site *must* include 'checkers.eu' in the names regardless of what ip address it actually resolves to.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, it seems like you are using a **SSL Certificate** which offering only **Single Server License policy**. As per SSL under this policy, you can only install SSL certificate on one domain, one IP address and one physical server. If you try to install it on same IP address it will never allow you.

You either need to purchase another server license from the Certificate Authority, or else get the SSL Certificate from Certificate Authorities which offers multiple server license such as (Comodo, Thawte, GeoTrust & RapidSSL).